# Alamofire session configurations are not reflected in the request

Tags: swift, alamofire

Alamofire Version: 5.1

We are modifying our alamofire session configuration as following:

```
let apiManager: Session = {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.af.default
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 20
        configuration.requestCachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringCacheData
        configuration.urlCache = nil
        let manager = Alamofire.Session(
            configuration: configuration,
            cachedResponseHandler:  ResponseCacher(behavior: .doNotCache)
        )
        return manager
    }()
```

And we are making the request as following

```
apiManager.request(
            url,
            method: .post,
            parameters: requestBodyParameters,
            encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
            headers: generateHeaders(enableAuth: authorisation) // to generate headers
        )
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response)
            }
        }
    }
```

But the request configurations is not updated, they remain at default values

```
[Timeout]
60
[Cache policy]
UseProtocolCachePolicy
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at the `URLRequest` generated by Alamofire which doesn't include the `URLSession`-level configuration, and which will never reflect the cache customization. If you want to see the actual `URLRequest` being performed after it passes through both Alamofire and `URLSession`, you can access the latest `URLSessionTask` that the Alamofire `Request` (in this case a `DataRequest`) performed by using `request.task`. However, like I said, this will never reflect the other behaviors you've attached, like a `ResponseCacher`, since those exist outside of the request pipeline.

Comment: I am also getting an error when request are made with expired access tokens.
CredStore - performQuery - Error copying matching creds.  Error=-25300, query={
    class = inet;
    "m_Limit" = "m_LimitAll";
    ptcl = htps;
    "r_Attributes" = 1;
    sdmn = "rffjjkqazc.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com";
    srvr = "rffjjkqazc.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com";
    sync = syna;
}